# React rendering issue with normalizer npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

My components are getting re-renders even if my childComponent is being updated, following is the JSON I am getting from api

```
{
"data": {
    "parent1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "xyz",
        "age": "50",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 100,
                "name": "pqr",
                "age": "30",
                "grandChildren": [
                    {
                        "id": 1000,
                        "name": "James",
                        "age": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 200,
                "name": "sty",
                "age": "10",
                "grandChildren": [
                    {
                        "id": 2000,
                        "name": "Sam",
                        "age": "3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I have normalized the above data to following with the help of [normalizer npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr)

`parentIds: [1]`

`parentDetails : {1: {name: xyz, age: 50, children: [100, 200]}}`

`parentDetails : {1: {name: xyz, age: 50, children: [100, 200]}}`

`childrenDetails: {100: {name: pqr, age: 30, grandChildren: [1000, 2000]}, 200: {....}}`

`grandChildrenDetails: {1000: {...}, 2000: {...}}`

and this is stored in redux

And the UI is nested one after another in a list having a toggle

> Parent 1
>
> - children
>
>   - grandChildren

There are 4 components

- Base component
- Parent component
- Children component
- GrandChildren component

To render UI I am looping through "**parentIds**" & getting **parentDetails** of that parentId, and calling "**Parent component**",

In that I am passing "*childrenDetails*" and "*grandChildrenDetails*" and "*parentObject*", in "parentComponent"

I am looping through **childrenIds** and calling **childrenComponent** with "*childrenObject*" and "*grandChildrenDetails*"

The problem statement is when I am **updating** a row of *grandChildren* all of my *parentComponent* rows, *childrenComponent* row are **getting re-rendered**

Used memo for all the components but as you can see I am passing grandChildrenDetails to all the components and that is why it is getting re-rendered

Can anyone suggest what should I do to stop the re-renders